# Android C# writeline command

Tags: c#, android

I've installed C#TOGO on my android device.
is there any way to use

```
console.writeline("DOESN'T WORK");
```

in this app?
When i use this command it says:
the name "console" does not exist in the current context
Thanks

Comment: Just type Console.WriteLine("Foo"); in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the name "console" does not exist in the current context", yes but **Console** does.
C# is case-sensitive!

```
Console.WriteLine("Works");

console.writeline("Doesnt");
```